# Cannot select elements with space with jquery after a html() in Internet Explorer 8, Firefox works fine

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following code that uses to display the value

```
<tr>
<td class="colheader"><b>Customer Name</b></td>
<td style="height: 25px; overflow:hidden;"><s:label cssClass="labelvalue" id="iocustomer" /></td>
</tr>
```

IN JQUERY, set the value

```
function setOrderInqResponse(data){
  $("#iocustomer").html(data.orderInq.customer);
}
```

The actual data come from an ajax request but the customer name can not be selected in IE!, it works fine in Firefox. what might be the wrong?

Comment: `<s:label />` isn't HTML. Is this _JSP_? _Struts2_ perhaps?...

Comment: What is the actual HTML output for that row (not the server-side template)?

Comment: <s:label/> is the Struts2 tag

Comment: What do you mean by the customer name cannot be selected?

Comment: Console errors? Are you using a `console.log` anywhere because it won't work in IE unless the console is already open.

Comment: Paul, Here is the HTML OUTput, it is same for both IE and FireFox.<tr>
 <td class="colheader"><b>Customer</b></td>
 <td style="height: 25px; overflow:hidden;">
  <li id="wwgrp_iocustomer" class="wwgrp">
   <div id="wwctrl_iocustomer" class="wwctrl">
     <label id="iocustomer" class="labelvalue" class="labelvalue">&nbsp;</label>
   </div>
   </li>
 </td>
</tr>

Comment: Barmar, in the browser, the text can not be select with mouse in IE

Comment: Jack, i am not using any console.log

Answer (score 0):

Instead of struts tags, use html label tag.